# How to customize a language input on linux?

Tags: input-language

I want to customize the Greek alphabet as to be able to depict accent marks for a Greek dialect. Greek keyboard layout is already able to use intonation marks for vowels when you press the ";" key next to L. So ι,ο,ε,α,and etc can get an intonation mark and be depicted as ί,ό,έ,ά. I want to add a "v" mark above the letters χ,σ,ζ also a double dot mark under α (something like ϊ but under α) when I press ";" prior to the letter. I want to do it on an ubuntu laptop but hopefully create a customized Greek input for Linux, Windows, Android and Apple. Does anyone have a clue how I can do that?